# Difference in linker-generated name (C++/C) ($$FYZAXXZ - $$J0YAXXZ)

Tags: c++

I am having trouble linking my project. I get this error message:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl TimerInit(void)" (?TimerInit@@$$FYAXXZ)
```

The function `TimerInit` is in a different .CPP file in the same project. When I use DUMPBIN to look at the contents of the corresponding .OBJ file, I see that the compiler generated this symbol:

```
?TimerInit@@$$J0YAXXZ
```

I can't figure out why that is - `'J0'` instead of `'F'`. Must be something with calling conventions.

This is with Visual Studio 2008, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Show the declaration of `TimerInit` in the header and the signature part of the definition where it's implemented.

Comment: Use extern C to, in a sense, standardise the exported names. Also, is this a 32 or 64 bit target?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `undname` command line tool, we can see that the symbol in the .obj is

```
Undecoration of :- "?TimerInit@@$$J0YAXXZ"
is :- "extern "C" void __cdecl TimerInit(void)"
```

while the one the linker is looking for is not `extern "C"`.

I don't have access to VS 2008 to check this, but it appears that wherever you define the `TimerInit` function, it is in an `extern "C"` declaration of some kind.  Newer versions of Visual Studio do not export mangled extern "C" names (`TimerInit` would be `_TimerInit` or just `TimerInit`, depending on the compiler version), and I am unsure what your declarations look like to produce this since you do not show them in the question.

Either remove the `extern "C"` in the definition of `TimerInit`, or consider upgrading to a more recent version of Visual Studio.